# How to create JSF messages with jGrowl

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, jgrowl

I need to display messages with [jGrowl](http://stanlemon.net/pages/jgrowl) like this:

[image]

I need to store the messages into the managed bean using `Map`. The tricky part is that I want to display the messages into the `Map` right after they are inserted. The solution I suppose will be to make Ajax calls infinitely to the server from the browser. How can I achieve this in JSF?

Comment: No, I haven't solve the problem with PrimeFaces. http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=22288

Answer (score 1):

It is really easy if you can use prime faces

in xhtml

```
<p:panel header="Map">  
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">  
        <h:outputText value="Map Info: " />   
        <p:inputText value="#{myBean.key}" label="Name"/>  
        <p:inputText value="#{myBean.value}" label="Name"/> 
    </h:panelGrid>  

    <p:commandButton value="Save" actionListener="#{myBean.save}" update="growl"/>  
</p:panel>
```

in java

public class MyBean {

```
private String key;  
private String value;  

public String getKey() {  
    return text;  
}  
public void setKey(String key) {  
    this.key = key;  
}

public String getValue() {  
    return value;  
}  
public void setValue(String value) {  
    this.value = value;  
}   

public void save(ActionEvent actionEvent) {  
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();  

    context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Successful", "Key : " + key + " Value : " + value));    
}
```

}

for more details use this link http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/growl.jsf